# Integrating Google Maps w/ WordPress - Infowindow not opening

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I am currently trying to incorporate a map on the homepage of my wordpress blog which will display a custom icon on a map based on a post content and customfield location.  I am very close and got everything working except the infowindow.  I get no errors and no window.  Your help is much appreciated.

I looked at similar questions and tried a few things but nothing worked.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
// setup map
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.109739, -118.351936);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


// icons
var bootIcon = '/images/icons/bootIcon.png';
var hikingIcon = '/images/icons/hikingIconSm.png';

// Init post Data
var i = 0;
var hikingPositions = new Array();
var hikingMarkers = new Array();
var hikingBlurbs = new Array();

<?php $hiking_query = new WP_Query('category_name=hiking_ctg&posts_per_page=4');
        while ($hiking_query->have_posts()) : $hiking_query->the_post();?>
            <?php $geoLoc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'longlat', true); ?>

            // Set Post data
            hikingPositions[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $geoLoc; ?>);
            hikingMarkers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: hikingPositions[i],
              map: map,
              icon: hikingIcon,
              title:"<?php the_title(); ?>"
            });

            hikingBlurbs[i] = '<div id="content"><h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1><div id="bodyContent"><p>.</p></div></div>'; 

            i++;

<?php endwhile; ?>


// Assign data to map
for(var j=0, marker; j < hikingMarkers.length; j++)
 {
     // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
     hikingMarkers[j].setMap(map);  
     marker = hikingMarkers[j]; 

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         infowindow.setContent(hikingBlurbs[j]);
         infowindow.open(map,this);
     });
 }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 initialize();
});

</script>
```

I still have a long way to finish all the functionality I am looking for, but for this build, this is the only thing not working.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
GeneralChaos

Comment: I am not sure if this is the problem, but when I try to display the position of the infowindow after the open command I get 'undefined'.

Comment: I also learned that you don't need to use setMap() because the marker will automatically be added to the map on creation if a map is assigned.

Comment: Now if I replace the j with a number (1-4) in the last 'for loop', it works.  I can even duplicate that code for a couple numbers and it still works. hmm.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there are more elegant solutions to this, but this worked.

I noticed that the event handler I was using was receiving the index only when the loop was over so I changed the marker to 'this' and added an 'content' value to the marker object.

Define the content array before the marker:

```
hikingBlurbs[i] = '<div id="infowindowContent"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1><div id="bodyContent"><p>.</p></div></div>';
```

Define your marker with the new content variable:

```
// Set Post data
hikingPositions[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $geoLoc; ?>);

hikingMarkers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: hikingPositions[i],
   map: map,
   icon: hikingIcon,
   title:"<?php the_title(); ?>",
   content: hikingBlurbs[i]
});
```

Now add the event listener with some simple changes:

```
// Assign data to map
for(marker in hikingMarkers)
 {
  google.maps.event.addListener(hikingMarkers[marker], 'mouseover', function() {
           infowindow.setContent(this.content);
           infowindow.open(map,this);
           });
 }
```

Let me know if you see a better way of doing this or you have any questions.

Best Regards,
GeneralChaos